# Using Maven for application settings

Tags: javascript, java, maven, yarnpkg

I currently have a project that uses Spring boot for the backend and React for the front. Everything is built and packaged using Maven and the frontend-maven-plugin plugin. Is there a way to store my application's configuration (web url, database info, API root url, ex.) in the pom.xml file and have settings be transposed into the various config and source files before compiling?

It would be nice to have a central location for the configuration details rather than hard-coded into the source and having multiple config files that need to be meddled with throughout the project.

I would even settle for maven handling java config and yarn handling the JavaScript's. At least then i can call yarn from maven and be down to two config files i need to modify.

Comment: In spring Boot you have `application.properties` or `application.yml` ?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Maven Resources. This plugin allows for filtering during the phase when copying resource files to the output.

Here is an example how you can filter and replace:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

You then can define properties in the Maven pom.xml and access the values with the expression language:

```
Hello ${name}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.